# How to draw numbers from a random list to use as Y coordinates for turtle graphics

Tags: python, list, integer, turtle-graphics

I am trying to generate a list of random Y coordinates for a turtle graphics program that needs to draw flowers, but to prevent the flowers from drawing over each other I need to draw them from back to front. What I need to do is sort the random list from largest to smallest, then have it draw the flowers in that order.

I have already set up the program to generate 9 random numbers and sort them from largest to smallest, but I don't know how to draw the numbers from that list in order and assign them the Y value of the flower

This is my code for generating the random list:

```
def draw_stem(t,StemX,StemY):
    StemYcoordinates=random.sample(range(-200,0),9)
    sorted(StemYcoordinates, key=int)
```

But I am having trouble connecting it to this part of the code where it goes to the xy position where I want the flower to be drawn

```
for i in range(9):
    t.setheading(90)
    t.pensize(7-(StemYcoordinate//40))
    t.color("#39ff14")
    t.penup()
    t.goto(StemX,StemYcoordinates)
    t.down()
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome To SO!! Could you please supply all of your code as I can't understand what you are trying to say. When I ran it, the code gave me `NameError`, so please supply all of the code.

Comment: As for your question, do you want the turtle to go to a specific coordinate, and then start to draw the flower? If that's what you want, I can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your code, you will need to use the `setpos()` method.

This method treats the screen in turtle like a coordinate plane with four quadrants.

[image]

Using this, set the x and y coordinates accordingly, or randomly if you want to.

For example, this puts the turtle in a random spot every time you run it:

```py
from turtle import *
t = Turtle()
t.penup()
from random import randint
x = randint(-200, 200)
y = randint(-200, 200)
t.setpos(x, y)
```

Hope this Helps!!!

Comment: If this answer is wrong, please tell me what I should do to improve it, as I didn't understand what you where exactly saying. English is my second language, so please do forgive me if my grammar isn't exact or anything. If you need additional help, please do ask as I am intermeddiate in python language, and begginer and javascript. Also, as a note, it helps if you supply all of your code, as I have to put the neccesary addons, and I may not know exacly what to put. Here it isn't a big deal, but when you have big programs, this becomes a huge neccesity for understanding. I geuss that's all !!!

Comment: With respect to, "you will need to use the setpos() method" the OP already uses `t.goto(StemX,StemYcoordinates)` in their code.  Turtle's `setpos()` and `setposition()` methods are *synonyms* for turtle's `goto()` method.

Comment: @cdlane They ask how to get a place and draw the flower. I thought they had trouble getting to a spot and drawing the flower. Please correct me If I am wrong on this aspect.

Comment: I don't read that in the question.  The closest it comes is "having trouble connecting it to this part of the code where it goes to the xy position where I want the flower to be drawn" which is about connecting two pieces of code together.  Once of those pieces has a `goto()` which goes to a position (spot) just fine.  Though this is a hard question to be sure about, as I noted in my own answer.

Comment: Ok My mistake @cdlane

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of your problem, you seem to want something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import sample, random

RADIUS = 100
PETALS = 10

def draw_petal(t, radius):
    heading = t.heading()
    t.circle(radius, 60)
    t.left(120)
    t.circle(radius, 60)
    t.setheading(heading)

def draw_flower(t):
    for _ in range(PETALS):
        draw_petal(t, RADIUS)
        t.left(360 / PETALS)

def draw_flowers(t, stemX):
    stemYcoordinates = sorted(sample(range(-200, 0), 9))

    for stemYcoordinate in stemYcoordinates:
        t.setheading(90)
        t.pensize(7 + stemYcoordinate // 40)
        t.color(random(), random(), random())
        t.penup()
        t.goto(stemX, stemYcoordinate)
        t.pendown()
        draw_flower(t)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

draw_flowers(turtle, 0)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

But if this isn't what you're looking for, take the time to reread and edit your question to clarify what you want to do.  Add more (if not all) of the code you've written so far, to make it clear what you need help with.